# BIRT Report Designer Issue?

Tags: javascript, birt

I have a parameter in my report that can only be 2 values. ALL or a number.

I want the user to be able to type ALL here, or a number like 12345678. Is this possible. I want the TextBox to refuse any input that is not either part of the word ALL or a number.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should just have a separate checkbox labelled "all", and a `number` field?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can do it,How you passed the parameters?
If you are passing parameters using jsp ,you can do it using java script validation

cheers